# Laravel response download

Tags: php, laravel, file, upload

I have the following file(picture) on my local :

`http://localhost:8080/uploads/user/10230313465a9fb5e0e65a85.73871653.png`

And i am using `response()->download(path)`, The above path is stored in a DB table column. 
The exception comes :

The file `http://localhost:8080/uploads/user/10230313465a9fb5e0e65a85.73871653.png` does not exist

But by checking the file in the browser does show the uploaded photo. Which means the file exists

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Absolute path to file
$file = public_path() . 'uploads/user/10230313465a9fb5e0e65a85.73871653.png';

return response()->download($file);
```

Please ensure that the file is stored within the public folder of Laravel. Also, you could also do the following:

```
// Absolute path to file
$file = public_path() . 'uploads/user/10230313465a9fb5e0e65a85.73871653.png';

if (! is_file($file)) {
    // File can not be found
    abort(404);
}

return response()->download($file);
```

This is a more appropriate response to return if the file can not be found.

I hope this helps.